# Get server information with invite link

Tags: discord.js

How can I get the server name, etc. by the invite link with discord.js?

I searched Google but there was no information about this.

Comment: discord.js does not provide a utility like that, it's up to you to map each invite to a specific guild and access it from your own cache

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Client#fetchInvite` that returns a Promise of an Invite like this :

```js
const {guild} = await client.fetchInvite("The Invite");
// 'guild' is a Guild.

// If you aren't in a async function, use this :
client.fetchInvite("The Invite").then((invite) => {
  // invite.guild is a Guild.
});
```